# Free resolution by Groebner basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, groebner-basis

I am studying approaches of Groebner basis in Homological and commutative algebra.

> I am so confused how can I find the minimal resolution for the below ideal
>   $$I=\langle yz-xw,y^3-x^2z,xz^2-y^2w,z^3-yw^2 \rangle$$

I already find the $s_{ij}$ but could not undrestand what should I do for the resolution.